# Trouble building JSON tree from non-relational database in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, recursion, tree-traversal

I am trying to build a script that will periodically iterate my non-relational database (firestore) recursively and will generate a JSON object from it.

I am able to iterate through all of the collections, documents and sub-collection to the very final tier, however I am having a difficult time in generating the JSON object in the correct format: either I get the two bottom tiers or just the two top ones. I also tried generating a new JSON object with every recursion and appending it to a global JSON object but this was also badly formatted.

After trying appending to a global JSON object without success I have decided to test my recursion by generating a folder system from the non-relational database which was successful. However, I would like to automate the process and generating a folder system is quite costly and ineffective.

For testing purposes and to eliminate possible error from the main script, I've built a small program with a given JSON data model:

```js
const data = {
  'root': {
    'doc1': {'id':1, 'value' : 545},
    'doc2': {'id':2, 'value' : 645},
    'doc3': {
      'id': 3,
      'subCol31': {'id':31, 'data' : {'value1': {'da' : 2, 'la': 3}, 'value2' : 545}},
      'subCol32': {'id':32, 'data' :  {'value1':31, 'data' :  {'data':{'data':{'id':321, 'data' : {'id':311, 'value' : 5435}}, 'value' : 1545}, 'value' : 45}}}
    },
    'doc4': {'id':4, 'age' : 125}
  }
}
var processed = {};

function isEmpty(obj) {
  let numProperties = 0;
  for (let property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      ++numProperties;
    }
  }
  return numProperties === 0;
}

function mapParentChildPairs(f, obj) {
  if (isEmpty(obj)) {
    return;
  } else {
    for (let item in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        f(item, obj[item]);
        processed[item] = obj[item];
        mapParentChildPairs(f, obj[item]);
      }
    }
  }
}

mapParentChildPairs(console.log, data);
console.log('processed', processed);
```

The result I am getting:

```
{ root:
{ doc1: { id: 1, value: 545 },
doc2: { id: 2, value: 645 },
doc3: { id: 3, subCol31: [Object], subCol32: [Object] },
doc4: { id: 4, age: 125 } },
doc1: { id: 1, value: 545 },
id: 4,
value: 45,
doc2: { id: 2, value: 645 },
doc3:
{ id: 3,
subCol31: { id: 31, data: [Object] },
subCol32: { id: 32, data: [Object] } },
subCol31: { id: 31, data: { value1: [Object], value2: 545 } },
data: { id: 311, value: 5435 },
value1: 31,
da: 2,
la: 3,
value2: 545,
subCol32: { id: 32, data: { value1: 31, data: [Object] } },
doc4: { id: 4, age: 125 },
age: 125 }
```

The result I want to achieve:

```
{'root': {
'doc1': {'id':1, 'value' : 545},
'doc2': {'id':2, 'value' : 645},
'doc3': {'id': 3,
'subCol31': {'id':31, 'data' : {'value1': {'da' : 2, 'la': 3}, 'value2' : 545}}, 'subCol32': {'id':32, 'data' :  {'value1':31, 'data' :  {'data':{'data':{'id':321, 'data' : {'id':311, 'value' : 5435}}, 'value' : 1545}, 'value' : 45}}}},
'doc4': {'id':4, 'age' : 125}}}
```

Expected to receive the same structure as the given json object, but received only the first two tiers.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I have added the desired result as well as the current one.

Comment: Have you tried researching in-order tree traversal javascript algorithm?

Comment: for me, the result looks like the given data. where is the difference?

Comment: In case you want to travers your JSON simply ? Made iterator IIFE which generate new object structure during construction and then all nodes are 2-way linked also include 2 iterators, probably DepthFirst is more straight forward. But do not understand why are you processing that JSON to generate same again ?? https://github.com/eltomjan/ETEhomeTools/blob/master/HTM_HTA/JSON_Iterator_IIFE.js